# npm express not installing command

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a mac and I am running the following code to install express as global:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

this is giving the following output

```
new-host:nodetraining admin$ sudo npm install -g express
express@4.9.6 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── finalhandler@0.2.0
├── vary@1.0.0
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── methods@1.1.0
├── serve-static@1.6.4
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@0.4.5
├── qs@2.2.4
├── on-finished@2.1.0 (ee-first@1.0.5)
├── etag@1.4.0 (crc@3.0.0)
├── debug@2.0.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── send@0.9.3 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.3 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.3)
├── accepts@1.1.1 (negotiator@0.4.8, mime-types@2.0.2)
└── type-is@1.5.2 (mime-types@2.0.2)
new-host:nodetraining admin$
```

however it is not installing the command module so I cannot use the following command:

```
express <projectname>
```

This is what happens when I try to use the express command anyways:

```
new-host:nodetraining admin$ express airline
-bash: express: command not found
new-host:nodetraining admin$
```

could someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Express Generator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-generator) to get the `express` command. I was confused with this as well ;)

Comment: I just did that it's still not working:

`code`new-host:nodetraining admin$ npm install express-generator
express-generator@4.9.0 ../../node_modules/express-generator
├── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
└── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
new-host:nodetraining admin$ express airline
-bash: express: command not found
new-host:nodetraining admin$`code`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Express Generator globally to be able to use the command

```
npm install -g express-generator
```